# What file structure to use when deploying a Flask (or any framework) app?

Tags: python, security, unix, nginx, flask

This is basically a Unix Filesystem Hierarchy question.

The basic structure of my application is as follows:

- nginx listens on 80/443, forwards traffic to the gunicorn app on port 5000.
- nginx thinks webroot is `/var/www/app_name`

Currently, my flask app is installed under `/var/www/app_name`. The python virtualenv is installed to `/var/www/app_name/env`, logs in `/var/www/app_name/log`, etc. Is this a concern? Wouldn't this make it possible that nginx might accidentally serve source files?

If not `/var/www/...`, what would be the right unixy place for a python web app of this nature? `/usr/local/...`?

Comment: Yes, this is a concern. There's no one right place to put it, but I often use /srv.

Comment: So since I posted I have been experimenting with approot = `/usr/local/www/app_name` and logroot = `/var/log/app_name` -- seems to be working great. I feel much more comfortable with that setup, and it lets me put a static "site down" deploy in `/var/www/app_name` which feels an appropriate a place for static files. (approot and logroot are just my ansible var names for those locations, they aren't anything special).